# Using 2 scroll views in a view while saving scroll position of each

Tags: swift, swiftui

I would like to modify my swift UI view so that I can have multiple scroll views. And only one view is displayed on the screen at a time based on which button is selected. I have already done so, but the problem I'm running into is saving the scroll position of each scroll view so that if the user slides to the other scroll view and comes back, then it's still at the same position. What's going on now is that the position of the scroll view is just reset to the top every time I switch between them.

```
import SwiftUI

struct test: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = fetcher()
    @State private var buttonOne: Bool = true
    @State private var buttonTwo: Bool = false
 
    var body: some View {
        VStack(){
            HStack() {
                Spacer()
                Button {
                    buttonOne = true
                    buttonTwo = false
                } label: {
                    ZStack{
                        Color(.blue)
                        Text("scroll view 2")
                    }.frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                }
                Button {
                    buttonOne = false
                    buttonTwo = true
                } label: {
                    ZStack{
                        Color(.blue)
                        Text("scroll view 1")
                    }.frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                }
                Spacer()
            }.padding(.bottom)
            if buttonOne{
                ScrollView {
                    LazyVStack {
                        ForEach(viewModel.content.indices, id: \.self) { i in
                            someView(content: i)
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else if buttonTwo {
                ScrollView {
                    LazyVStack {
                        ForEach(viewModel.content.indices, id: \.self) { i in
                            someView(content: i)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using your views inside if condition you need to use TabView() for this scenario. Have a look at below code and assign unique tag to each view inside the TabView. This will resolve you scroll view as well.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = fetcher()
    @State private var buttonOne: Bool = true
    @State private var buttonTwo: Bool = false
    @State private var selection = 0
 
    var body: some View {
        VStack(){
            HStack() {
                Spacer()
                Button {
                    buttonOne = true
                    buttonTwo = false
                } label: {
                    ZStack{
                        Color(.blue)
                        Text("scroll view 2")
                    }.frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                }
                Button {
                    buttonOne = false
                    buttonTwo = true
                } label: {
                    ZStack{
                        Color(.blue)
                        Text("scroll view 1")
                    }.frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                }
                Spacer()
            }.padding(.bottom)
            
            TabView(selection: $selection) {
                
                ScrollView {
                    LazyVStack {
                        ForEach(viewModel.content.indices, id: \.self) { i in
                            someView(content: i)
                        }
                    }
                }.tag(0)
                
                ScrollView {
                    LazyVStack {
                        ForEach(viewModel.content.indices, id: \.self) { i in
                            someView(content: i)
                        }
                    }
                }.tag(1)
                
            } //: TabView
            .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never))

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a little comment, for anyone interested, to switch the tabs using the buttons like above, you can just add in selection = 0 or selection = 1, based on which button you want to correspond to the tab.

Comment: can you look at this question also please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76624877/swift-long-press-gesture-only-works-on-link-and-not-on-text-portion